# ProxyPass for https not working

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, mod-proxy

I'm having set of codes in tomcat `(port:8080)` and another set of codes in apache `(port:80)`. Now the default port I have set is apache **(document root: /var/www/html)** and for tomcat **(/usr/.../webapps/ROOT)**

Now tomcat codebase is running in `https:// www.example.com`
and apache codebase is running in `http://ww.example.com`

I have written proxy as

```
ProxyPass /req https://example.com/req
ProxyPassreverse /req https://example/req
```

All the request from http, which contains **/req** will go to `https://example.com/req.`

But the problem is, it is redirected into **http://example.com/req**

what can I do to **redirect to https** or what can I do to **run tomcat in "http"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add port to redirect, rewrite the proxy pass as,

```
ProxyPass /req https://example.com:8080/req
ProxyPassreverse /req https://example:8080/req
```